How to Access ngControl Property Inside a Directive in Angular 17
I'm trying to use a simple radio button group with ngModel in Angular 17. Additionally, I have a directive (appTest) and inside this directive, I need to access the ngControl property.
<div class="example-radio-group">
  <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="modelValue">
    <mat-radio-button appTest value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button appTest value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button appTest value="3">Option 3</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button appTest value="4">Option 4</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="5">Option 5</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="6">Option 6</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>

In Angular 6, this worked fine, but I am having trouble getting it to work in Angular 17. Below are my examples and the relevant code.
Example in Angular 6 (Works):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-inputs-ymje36?file=main.ts
Example in Angular 17 (Not Working):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/playground-angular-17-material-nsu3nd-y41cz2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

your ngControl is the control inject in constructor (not the @ContentChild)
NOTE: To get the "value" enclosed by a setTimeout to give time to Angular "repaint" if you use ngOnInit. Idem when you use ContentChild to get the "Test2Directive"
  @ContentChild(NgControl) _elements: NgControl; //<--this is nothing

  @ContentChild(Test2Directive) _elementss: Test2Directive;

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
       ..here you have the "ngControl"...
  }

ngOnInit(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(this.ngControl.control.value); 
      console.log(this._elementss); 
    })
}


but why it was working in angular 6 ?

I imagine is because material (really I'd have to check the code of the mat-radio-group in so early version)
